# Popup Window from FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a FormView that has two buttons on them.  What I need to happen is when the user clicks on the buttons, a popup window is displayed.  The data in this window is being pulled from a stored procedure in which I will need to pass variables.  Can someone supply code on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new page. This is your popup (ie popup). On the your calling page add a hyperlink that calls you popup page but make sure the Target attribute is set to _new which tells the link to open a new browser instance.

```
<a href="Popup.aspx" target="_new">Open popup page.</a>
```

In your pop up page you would then call your ADO.net sql specific code in the Page_Load event.

Are you passing a url encoded variable to this page?

Comment: I need it to be a "true" popup window.  Can't take the user to a new page.